# Robot Framework - run keyword if file exists

Tags: robotframework

How can you run keywords in the robot framework if the file exists in the filesystem?
For example:

```
Run Keyword If    ${filename} exists    Delete File
```

Comment: Check if file exits using the OS lib then put the return value into the run keyword if.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[OperatingSystem](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html) library could be used for this, even though there's not exactly any keyword for what you need. But you can get creative and perhaps use `Get File`, `Get File Size`, `List Files In Directory`, `Run And Return Rc` or even something else. There are also keywords like `File Should Exist`, `File Should Not Exist`, `Should Exist`. Perhaps you can change your code so you can use these.

Or you create your own simple library:

**Libraries/file.py**

```py
import os

def file_exists(file):
    return os.path.isfile(file)
```

import it and use it like you mentioned in your question:

**Tests/test.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ../Libraries/file.py    

*** Test Cases ***
Test File Exists
    ${fileExists}=    File Exists    test.robot
    Run Keyword If    ${fileExists} is True    Log To Console    Exists!
```

Answer (score 1):

When I need this kind of action, I code something like that... maybe can work for you.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Process

*** Variables ***
@{FILES}    ${CURDIR}/someFolder/aaa.pdf
...         ${CURDIR}/someFolder/bbb.pdf

*** Test Cases ***
Check and Delete Files
    FOR    ${file}    IN    @{FILES}
        ${out} =    run process    ls    ${file}
        run keyword if    ${out.rc} == 0    Delete File    ${file}    
    END

*** Keywords ***
Delete File
    [Arguments]    ${f}
    ${o} =    run process    rm    -f    ${f}
    Should Be Equal As Integers   ${o.rc}    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the File status and then use the status as

```
${file_exists}=  Run Keyword and Return Status    File Should Exist  test.robot
IF  ${file_exists}
    Log   File Exists
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without custom Libs, just evaluate inline Python code

```
${file_name}=    Set Variable    MY_FILE.txt
Run Keyword If   ${{os.path.exists($file_name)}} is True    Log To Console    "file exist"
```